# Automatic crop filling in HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, tumblr, crop

I am working on a Tumblr blog, in which photos are cropped to a square. The effect works when the photos are portrait but not landscape. Instead, the photos are fully shown as landscape. Look at http://hugowolfdesigns.tumblr.com/ to see what I mean (the first and second photos show what I do not desire; the third photo shows the effect I'm trying to achieve).

What code can I use to make photos crop all the way to a square shape?

This is what I use to crop it currently:

```
<div id = "photo">
<a href="{permalink}"><img class = "default" img src="{PhotoURL-500}" width="250"/></a>
</div>
```

However if I just use a `height="250"` it just stretches the photo, rather than cropping it.

Comment: If you can, set each image as background. Then you could use `background-position: center;`

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign a width or height to an image depending on whether it is a landscape or portrait image. In this instance I would control the width/height in CSS, not inline. I would also use jQuery to assign the correct class to the correct image type.

Example http://jsfiddle.net/xukcc3sv/

CSS

```
img.portrait, img.square {
    width: 100px;
}
img.landscape {
    height: 100px;
}
```

jQuery

```
// I've added a callback within the addClass function to prevent multiple use.

$('img').addClass(function () {
    if (this.height === this.width) {
        return 'square';
    } else if (this.height > this.width) {
        return 'portrait';
    } else {
        return 'landscape';
    }
});
```

This is a quick example using a portrait image and a landscape image.

**CSS Only solution**

Example http://jsfiddle.net/xukcc3sv/1/

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    background-image: url('image.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

If you use the image as a background and assign the background property 'cover' then it will auto scale   ensuring complete coverage.